# AWS Redshift copy command from s3 with named profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can use AWS cli like this:

```
aws --profile prfName s3 ls s3://mybucket
```

but when I use redshift like this:

```
copy eventStream.Events_Adobe
from 's3://cassemrtest/eventStream.csv'
region 'us-east-1'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=Rxxxxx[;token=xxxxxx]';
```

I get this error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: S3ServiceException:The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.,Status 403,Error SignatureDoesNotMatch,Rid xxxxxxxx,ExtRid xxxxxx
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  S3ServiceException:The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.,Status 403,Error SignatureDoesNotMatch,Rid xxxxx,ExtRid xxxxxx
  code:      8001
  context:   Listing bucket=cassemrtest prefix=eventStream.csv
  query:     1690
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:529
  process:   padbmaster [pid=25203]
  -----------------------------------------------;

Execution time: 0.3s
1 statement failed.
```

I think this is because I'm missing the profile name...how do I put in the profile name like I do when I use AWS CLI?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a bad set of credentials.

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is used on a computer (either your own, or on Amazon EC2) to communicate with the AWS APIs. You can use a local credentials file to authenticate to AWS. In your case, the credentials file contains multiple credentials stored as profiles, so the `--profile` parameter tells it which profile to use.

However, this credentials file is **not** used when sending commands to Amazon Redshift. Communications to Redshift is done via SQL rather than the AWS CLI.

When using the Redshift `COPY` command, provide the Access Key and Secret Key directly, rather than referring to a credentials file. It should look something like:

```
copy eventStream.Events_Adobe
from 's3://cassemrtest/eventStream.csv'
region 'us-east-1'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=AKIAJ24FFOOBAR7VPMCT;aws_secret_access_key=2IpmAExampleKeyYsiXrqwyfza';
```

You most likely won't require the `Token`, since it is only used with temporary credentials.